# Как присвоить к слову число

Tags: python, циклы

*Делаю программу на python одну и столкнулся с одной, я думаю, простой проблемой. Я не знаю как перед словом с новой строки поставить цифру. Например у меня есть строчки:*

```
Василий
Марго
Александр
```

А я хочу чтобы программа вместо меня ставила последовательно каждому слову своё число. Выглядит это вот так:

```
[1]Василий
[2]Марго
[3]Александр
```

*И так далее. Как это сделать? Посмотрел везде нигде не нашёл ответа :(*

Comment: на входе что - срока, список?

Comment: на входе файл со строками который я прочитал через метод read()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перебора значений с получением номера можно использовать `enumerate`, а для формирования строки с номером использовать f-строки

Пример:

```
words = ['Василий', 'Марго', 'Александр']

for i, word in enumerate(words, 1):
    print(f'[{i}] {word}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Объедините слова в структуре хранения данных (коллекции/массиве), пробегитесь циклом for по выбранной структуре и выводите значение переменной цикла (счетчика) перед словом

Comment: извините, но я начинающий, по-этому для меня пока сложно понять как это сделать